# Flex debugger to verbose?

Tags: apache-flex, flexbuilder

I am attempting to use the flex debugger and I am CONSTANTLY getting messages such as:

```
10694 AVMINF: MTHD Object () @ 0x0856C618
10694 AVMINF: MTHD flash.events::Event/ctor () @ 0x07084800
10694 AVMINF: MTHD SetIntervalTimer/onTimer () @ 0x085CBF2C
10694 AVMINF: MTHD Function/http://adobe.com/AS3/2006/builtin::apply () @ 0x07084800
10694 AVMINF: MTHD mx.core::Application/debugTickler () @ 0x0C7BE415
10694 AVMINF: MTHD flash.utils::Timer/get repeatCount () @ 0x085CBB93
12194 AVMINF: MTHD flash.utils::Timer/tick () @ 0x085D17EE
12194 AVMINF: MTHD flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch () @ 0x07084800
12194 AVMINF: MTHD flash.events::TimerEvent () @ 0x085D168E
12194 AVMINF: MTHD flash.events::Event () @ 0x085D4502
```

Eventually my debugger will hang. Is there a way I can lower the verbosity setting on the flex debugger?

I have also uninstaller and re-installed Flash, Flash Debugger, Flex and Java.

Comment: I've never seen anything like that before and suspect the solution has nothing to do w/ verbosity.  Which Flex SDK are you using? Which version of the Flash Player?  Are you seeing these messages in the console or are they runtime errors?

Comment: I'm seeing them in the console. I am using Flex Builder 3.2 and the 3.2 SDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have your debugging configured manually using an **mm.cfg** file in your user directory, then the settings in there might be the problem.

This thread shows a similar full stack tracing problem, and someone suggests changing `AS3Trace=1` to `AS3Trace=0`: http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?t=357850

Comment: This was exactly it! Not sure how this file got created, but I found and changed the settings. Worked like a charm after.